# Highcharts speedometer gauge change label

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I want to implement speedometer to display internet bandwidth speed but I want to change its number sequence. I have search a lot but couldn't find anything.

Please find below code snippet for the highchart gauge. I want to change the label (number). In below example number sequence is 0,10,20,30,...,100.

But my requirement is number sequence should be 0,1,5,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100

Check following image of gauge:
 [Highchart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM2qt.png)

But my requirement is number sequence should be 0,1,5,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100

Is there any way to change the numbers ?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Speedometer'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150,
        background: [{
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF'],
                    [1, '#333']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '109%'
        }, {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#333'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
            // default background
        }, {
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '105%',
            innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
    },

    // the value axis
     yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,

            minorTickInterval: 'auto',
            minorTickWidth: 1,
            minorTickLength: 10,
            minorTickPosition: 'inside',
            minorTickColor: '#666',

            tickPixelInterval: 30,
            tickWidth: 2,
            tickPosition: 'inside',
            tickLength: 10,
            tickColor: '#666',
            labels: {
                step: 2,
                rotation: 'auto'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Mbps'
            },
            plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 60,
                color: '#55BF3B' // green
            }, {
                from: 60,
                to: 80,
                color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
            }, {
                from: 80,
                to: 100,
                color: '#DF5353' // red
            }]
        },
    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

},
// Add some life
function (chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
        setInterval(function () {
            var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                newVal,
                inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

            newVal = point.y + inc;
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }

            point.update(newVal);

        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify specific tick-positions using `yAxis.tickPositions` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions)).

In your case:

```
yAxis: {
    tickPositions: [0,1,5,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
}
```

In your example you have `yAxis.labels.step` set to `2`, which needs to be removed so that you don't skip over any labels for your defined `tickPositions` (unless you want to that is).

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/z3k8yzcf/) of your suggested labels.

Comment: @Halvor...Thanks for tha answer, it solved my issue.